# Web service only works when NO port is specified

Tags: web-services, http, port

I have a tool retrieving RSS feeds. To test, I was using http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss .

While the browser is able to retrieve the feed, by tool was getting a 404.
I noticed other RSS tools that failed with the same error.

Investigating the WireShark logs, I noticed that the difference was that my tool used `Host: rss.cnn.com:80` while the browser used `Host: rss.cnn.com`.

And indeed, removing the port completely fixed it.

But what does it mean?

Comment: Not sure. The browser uses port 80 as well (default port). If you go to http://rss.cnn.com:80/rss/edition.rss it works fine.

Comment: Look at your Wireshark, even if you do port 80 in the browser, it won't be there on the network level.

Comment: Actually, at least in Chrome, it automatically removes the 80 from the URL bar even.

Comment: Yes I think that is because 80 is the default HTTP port. If you put anything else it will not remove it

Comment: Right, but if you try a tool such as http://www.soapui.org/ to make a request with and without the port 80, you'll see the difference.